# ScrollView that deletes image in based on location

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, uiscrollview

I have made a scrollview, and made an array of images (which I will later add an option for the user to post images into that array and friends images will fill into that array) and want to have the user be able to see a photo and it tracks it.

I have created a for loop that added photos into the array, but when I created an if statement to take out an item in the array, I got an error because I would remove the image[i] from the array and I kinda know why this is happening, but want to fix it. So basically I need to take out an image in the array. 
Please help me out I'm still learning.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var imageArray = [UIImage]()

@IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mainScrollView.frame = view.frame
    imageArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai6"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai2"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai7"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai4"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai3"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai5"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DigitalDrawingPreview"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "denarus"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai1")]
    for i in 0..<imageArray.count  {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = imageArray[i]
        let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)

        mainScrollView.contentSize.width = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
        mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    }
    for i in 0..<imageArray.count {
        if (i >= 2) {
            imageArray.remove(at: (i - 2))
        }
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Thank you fellow better programmers.

Comment: I really can't understand what your trying to do here. Can you please explain it a little more? is this all of your code?

Comment: pretty much yeah, after user swipes image, the image they just swiped should delete, but i did 2 images back instead of the last image

Comment: So basically you want to delete the image that goes out of view so the user can not scroll back to it? If so, how are you detecting all this? where is the code to find out when the user has scrolled past the image so you can delete it?

Comment: ahh that makes sense... im new...

Comment: Well then I suggest you start by reading some tutorials on UIScrollView. Specially the scrollViewDidScroll delegate method. Another suggestion is to look into pageViewController. I think it would be better for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove an element from a array while traversing it so you had to use a temp array

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var imageArray = [UIImage]()

@IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mainScrollView.frame = view.frame
    imageArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai6"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai2"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai7"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai4"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai3"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai5"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DigitalDrawingPreview"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "denarus"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai1")]
    for i in 0..<imageArray.count  {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = imageArray[i]
        let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)

        mainScrollView.contentSize.width = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
        mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)


    }
    let tempArr = imageArray
    for i in 0..<tempArr.count {
        if (i >= 2) { // Breakpoint here
            imageArray.remove(at: (i - 2))
        }

    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

use step over to go through each line of for loop until it crashes and then print the value of i at that time by hovering cursor over it or type command at console `po i` and enter
[image]

Comment: Hmm Varun Naharia, im still getting the error: fatal error: Index out of range; and the error seems to be on the imageArray.remove(at; (i - 2)) line.

Comment: place a breakpoint on for loop and check on which condition it throws error

Comment: yes Varun Naharia, i updated the photo did not see breakpoint

Comment: where you update the image ? what do you mean by  "did not see breakpoint" ?

Comment: Varun Naharia , I know why the I can not just take out an image of an array with a for loop in this case, I am how I can, which am happy you shared the temp array

Comment: I did not see your edited code sample on your answer at first, so I breakpointed the for loop and not the if statement here is the image of the post breakpoint execution http://imgur.com/a/O0C2d Varun Naharia

Comment: don't post image just debug the code and check why it crashes and show the i value at the time of crash